# Laravel SASS, do I need a webhosting which has Ruby install to be able to use SASS?

Tags: ruby, laravel, sass

I've read that SASS uses Ruby to compile. I have a webhosting at One.com, I don't think they support Ruby. Am I able to run SASS on it?

Comment: Usually SASS is compiled in CSS in development and the production server only serves the CSS

Comment: @lukasgeiter ah makes sense, didn't thought about it that way. Thanks.

Comment: @lukasgeiter write it as an answer, so I can close the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually SASS is compiled in CSS *in development* and the production server only serves the CSS.

You would need Ruby if you wanted to compile SASS though. Sometimes that's needed to create more dynamic stylesheets although I'd generally advice against it because it slows down performance.

Answer (score 2):

You actually do not need to use ruby to compile sass. There are a few alternatives.

If you are using Laravel 5 you can do this with the new [elixir](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/elixir#usage) feature which uses gulp to process tasks.

Or you could use [gulp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sass) along side Laravel 4.

Or you could use [grunt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-sass).

All of these options use [libsass](http://libsass.org/) in the background instead of ruby.

Comment: True that. I think I've been a bit too early with asking questions. I was thinking, if I couldn't use SASS online, why even bother using it. So when I start digging in, I realized Gulp just makes a regular .css file. Perfect! Thanks anyways for the information.

Comment: You will run into issues with elixir if you plan on using actual SASS, with .sass extension.  The .sass files need gulp-ruby-sass to compile so if you stick with .scss you'll be alright.

Comment: Matthew, gulp-sass uses libsass to compile. Can you provide evidence that libsass doesn't compile .sass files? It's supposedly a complete port of the ruby sass compiler into C for faster compile times.